# Pubnub in ios What is cipher and secret key used

Tags: ios, pubnub

I am using pubnub example code in which it required a channel number which i have but it also required cipher and secret key which i don't have so please tell me what is cipher and secret key used in pubnub

Comment: Both `cipher_key` and `secret_key` are optional.  **`cipher_key`** is for symmetric cryptography/encryption.

Answer (score 1):

## What is a **Cipher Key** vs **Secret Key**

#### Cipher Key

A **Cipher Key** is the "secret" or "password" used in **Symmetric Cryptography Algorithms** such as AES256.  The [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/)  data streaming network provides embedded AES256 encryption options.  We invested in providing cross-device compatible AES256, with your iOS, Android and 50 more SDKs we allow apps to communicate using the same algorithm securely.  When you specify the `cipher_key` optional parameter with a text string cipher, you automatically enabled symmetric encryption/decryption communication mode with your supplied cipher key.

#### Secret Key

The **Secret Key** is also just as important to keep super secret!  The PubNub SDK offers administrative controls when the **Secret Key** is provided at SDK initialization time.  These administrative capabilities include:

1. Grant/Revoke and Audit of [ACL Access Management when PubNub Access Manager](http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/access-manager/) is enabled.
2. Reading Account-wide Settings.
3. Reading Analytics and Usage Metrics.
4. Changing Account-wide Settings and Add-ons.
5. Managing Access Keys.